# Cordova - ios - open in maps app - not opening - 'maps://?q='

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, maps

i have checked my config.xml, and

```
<allow-intent href="maps:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

and my code is

```
window.open('maps://?q=', latLng, '_system');
```

and

```
latLng = 'lat,Lng'
```

and i have tried

```
'maps:q='
'maps:'
'maps:0, 0?q='
'maps:daddr='
'maps://maps.apple.com/?q='
```

Answer (score 0):

For Google or Android, you should still use the web url, it will automatically redirect to the app, e.g:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=<lat>,<long>&amp;ll=
```

As for Apple maps, the same principle applies, just change the protocol:

```
maps://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=<lat>,<long>&amp;ll=
```

Comment: Right, sorry. I've revised my answer